# Styling own template

Tags: templates

I have an own template here where the [sidebar](http://konzertagentur-koerner.de/Timo/?page_id=839) looks different than the others: the sidebar is BELOW right the main content and not on the side.
My code:

```
<div id="sidebar"><?php echo get_sidebar()?></div>
```

I know this is CSS, but can you help how to structure the index.php and page-slug.php to have the same design for all pages.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen you Html structure, You need to change structure like this..

Follow this structure for you own template file...

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <!-- Here goes the header part -->
    </div>

    <div id="main">
        <!-- Here goes the main content part -->
    </div>

    <div id="sidebar">
        <!-- Here goes the sidebar part --> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried it but it still does not work. I added the header div